# UML Design Pattern and implementation into C++ classes

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, uml

I am trying to learn Adapter Design Pattern UML with C++ and in one of the videos in youtube displayed this content - my issue is translating the UML picture to C++ class / code:

[image]

What I really get confused is:

1. The Clinet -------> [solid line] association to interface Target. What does this means generally I have seen classes implementing interface something like Adapter class implementing Target
2. What does the content Adapter is composed with the adaptee means here - if it is containership then does it completely or partially owns it?

Below is the code implementation that I can think of it:

```
class Target
{
public:
 void virtual ServiceA() = 0;
}; 

class Client : public Target
{
public:
Client(){}
void ServiceA() override {}
};

class Adaptee
{
public:
Adaptee(){}
void ServiceX(){}
};

class Adapter : public Target
{
public:
Adapter(){}
void ServiceA() override {adaptee.serviceX();}
Adaptee adaptee;
};

int main()
{
.....
}
```

How inside main we would code up? Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Clinet -------> [solid line] association to interface Target. What does this means generally I have seen classes implementing interface something like Adapter class implementing Target

no, the *Client* does not implement/inherit *Target*, so

```
class Client : public Target {
   ...
};
```

is wrong.

The association can indicate *Client* has an attribute typed *Target* even the real type is *Adapter*, the interface *Target* is used to hide *Adapter*. Of course C++ the type of the attribute is not `Target` but a pointer to whatever the way to manage it.

But the association can be used just to indicate the *Client* see/use a *Target* (rather than an *Adapter* and its associated *Adaptee*) even in that case a dependency was better. The instance of *Adapter* can be given to an operation of *Client* through a parameter typed `Target *` is C++ or another way managing a pointer to *Target*

> What does the content Adapter is composed with the adaptee means here - if it is containership then does it completely or partially owns it?

The *Adapter* needs an associated *Adaptee*, the multiplicity is 1, but note the association is not a composition so it does not *completely owns it* if I well understand what you mean. Note the association is not even a aggregation even the note in the diagram speak about *composed*.

> How inside main we would code up? Please explain.

the program can be :

```
#include <iostream>

class Target {
  public:
    virtual void serviceA() = 0;
};

class Adaptee {
  public:
    void serviceX() { std::cout << "serviceX" << std::endl; }
};

class Adapter : public Target {
  public:
    Adapter(Adaptee & a) : adaptee(a) {}
    virtual void serviceA() { adaptee.serviceX(); }
  private:
    Adaptee & adaptee;
};

class Client {
  public:
    void work(Target & t) { t.serviceA(); }
};

int main()
{
  Adaptee adaptee;
  Adapter adapter(adaptee);
  Client client;
  
  client.work(adapter);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
serviceX
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lucid explanation

Comment: @Programmer you welcome. The Adapter pattern is used to transform an interface from one class to another conforming to that expected by the client. The adapter allows classes to collaborate when they could not have done so due to incompatible interfaces.